# Detect that the "multitasking bar" was triggered

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6

Is there any way to detect that the "multitasking bar" (pressing home button twice) was triggered?

I think there should be some notification telling that the UIView viewport (or something like that) was modified, is that the easiest/less complex solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to detect that the recently-used-apps list was presented. Your app will be notified that it is no longer active but this happens for many other cases as well.